# $\mathbb{Z}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I have read that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a vector space over any field. But i am looking at the following:

"Determine the multiplication form for elements in $\mathbb{Z}$ so that $\mathbb{Z}$ become a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$."

My lecture gimme a challenge like that. And i tried to make my own multiplicator, but i was wondering about: is that really possible?

Comment: Oh, actually: Do you want $ℤ$ to be equipped with the usual addition?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible if you also allow $ℤ$ to carry a different addition than the usual one.

*Hint*. What’s the cardinality of $ℚ$?

No, it is not possible if you want to preserve the usual addition of $ℤ$.

*Hint*. Otherwise, what would be $\frac 1 2 · 1_ℤ + \frac 1 2 · 1_ℤ$ where “$+$” would be the usual addition in $ℤ$ and $·~\colon ℚ × ℤ → ℤ$ is any product that is satisfying the vector space axioms)?

Comment: so the answer is that any bijection $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}^n$ is ok for making  $\mathbb{Z} $ a $n$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 Yeah, but the addition on $ℤ$ gets really weird. I’d have no intuition for such an implementation of $ℚ^n$.

Comment: if $\phi$ is a bijection $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}^n$ then for $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}$ the addition is $u+v = \phi^{-1}(\phi(u) + \phi( v))$ and for $a \in \mathbb{Q}, u \in \mathbb{Z}$ the multiplication by a constant is $a u = \phi^{-1}(a\phi(u) )$

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, was this a question?

Comment: @ k.stm .. not anymore, I wanted to know the exact definition of the vector space

Comment: so the example of different addition? I am confused to guess it...